# Pythonで関数の戻り値（行列計算のベクトル）を配列で表したい

Tags: python, python3, numpy, array

下記のようなコードで関数 `pc.pcoef` で行列計算をして返ってきたベクトルを配列で表示したいのですが、うまくいきません。どなたか解決法をご教授ください。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
for k in range(8):
        for i in range(6):
            z0    = 0                                    # L.E. camber line location
            zr    = 0.1+0.2*new_population[k,0]          # location of camber crest(y)
            z1    = -0.3*new_population[k,1]             # location of camber T.E.(y)
            dz0   = 2*new_population[k,2]                # slope of L.E.
            dz1   = -0.5-1.5*new_population[k,3]         # slope of T.E.
            dzr   = 0                                    # slope of crest

            cm_coef=pc.pcoef(x0,xr,x1,z0,zr,z1,dz0,dz1,dzr)
            zsft[k]=zr+zt/2
    for k in range(8):
        for i in range(6):
            print(cm_coef[k,i])
```

実行結果は以下の通りです。

```
print(cm_coef[k,i])
 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

この部分の後でcm_coefを使って5次の関数を作りたいのですが、タプルだとうまくいかないのでしょうか？

追記です。最初のiのループはいらないようです。
さらにprint(cm_coef)の結果を載せます。
なんかわかりそうな気がします。

```
[[ 0.        ]
 [ 0.8689419 ]
 [-2.6802233 ]
 [ 3.34391096]
 [-1.01442115]
 [-0.60621196]]
[[ 0.        ]
 [ 0.30732422]
 [ 2.0012324 ]
 [-3.92897529]
 [ 1.03923625]
 [ 0.37938151]]
[[ 0.        ]
 [ 1.49308562]
 [-4.07762968]
 [ 5.43484588]
 [-3.10940638]
 [ 0.20196107]]
[[  0.        ]
 [  1.88226751]
 [ -9.13169862]
 [ 20.9972712 ]
 [-22.02983331]
 [  8.05246197]]
[[ 0.        ]
 [ 0.82515095]
 [-1.64132387]
 [ 4.19406298]
 [-6.31678378]
 [ 2.65285626]]
[[ 0.        ]
 [ 1.66204428]
 [-5.12235318]
 [ 9.30373519]
 [-8.80369057]
 [ 2.82992897]]
[[ 0.        ]
 [ 0.99575797]
 [-3.21823631]
 [ 4.6837967 ]
 [-2.69326248]
 [ 0.18003859]]
[[ 0.        ]
 [ 1.04588867]
 [-1.33639327]
 [ 2.67285108]
 [-5.13182913]
 [ 2.72569873]]
```

cm_coefの定義は以下の通りです。

```
cm_coef=np.zeros((6,8), dtype=np.float64)
```

このようにして下記 `cm_coef[k][i]` に設定するとエラーが出ます。
まだデバッグが必要のようです。

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: 取り敢えずはメッセージのとおり`cm_coef[k,i]`にカンマが入ってタプルになっているから良くないのでは？ それでうまくいくかは別にして`cm_coef[k][i]`に変えてみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: cm_coef[k][i]ではうまくいかないようです。そのエラー結果がIndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1となっています。pythonに詳しい方なら簡単なのでしょうか？

Comment: `print(cm_coef)` の結果から(何やら表示がおかしいのですが)、`cm_coef` の shape は `(8, 6, 1)` になりますね。

Comment: やはりそうでしたかprint(cm_coef)で出力したときたまたま別のprint(8)というのも出していた時(6，1)が8個あるということがわかりました。それから配列の結合を調べたりしていましたが、まだ解決に至っていません。

Comment: `cm_coef`とか`pc.pcoef`で検索したらこの記事がヒットしましたが、何か関係ありますかね。[翼型点列データを出力するpythonスクリプト](http://waku2005.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/02/06/160358), [dqsis/parsec-airfoils](https://github.com/dqsis/parsec-airfoils)

Comment: 関係はありますが、自分は改善しようとしています。引き続き（6，1）を（8，6）にする方法を考えています。

Comment: この記事 [NumPy配列ndarrayの要素・行・列を取得（抽出）、代入](https://note.nkmk.me/python-numpy-select-element-row-column-array/) とか見ると、`cm_coef`がnumpyの配列ではなくPython標準のリストに変わってしまっているのでは？ `pc.pcoef()`戻り値の`cm_coef`への代入を正しく行えば`cm_coef[k,i]`で問題無いと思われます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記のようにして自己解決しました。

```
for k in range(8):
　　　　co=coef.reshape([6])
      　for i in range(6):
                cm_coef[k][i]=co[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

ソースコードのインデントが崩れていたりお使いの変数の定義が分からなかったりするので正確なところは言えませんが、少なくとも今出ているエラーは `cm_coef[k, i]` ではなく `cm_coef[k][i]` と書くことで直せます。普通の Python の多次元配列には後者のようにして添え字を指定してください。前者のような書き方をするのは NumPy array などライブラリのものです。

コメントでは更に `cm_coef[k][i]` と書くと `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1` エラーが出たと書かれていますが、これはエラーメッセージに書かれている通り添え字が out of bounds したことによるエラーです。つまり `cm_coef[k]` の長さ以上の添え字が指定されてしまっています。もし `cm_coef[k][1]` が存在するはずなのであれば `cm_coef` の定義にバグがあるので確認してください。